# How do we add up length of sub-intervals whose start-points belong to fractions with an even or odd denominator less than $n$?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we divide $[0,1]$ into sub-intervals whose start-points contains fractions in $[0,1]$ with a denominators less than integer $n$. Then suppose we add the lengths of sub-intervals whose start-points contain even denominators and odd denominators.

For example, suppose $n=4$.

We take fractions in $[0,1]$, when reduced, have a denominator less than 4 and delete repeated fractions. (Whole numbers have a denominator of $1$.)

$$0/1,1/4,1/3,1/2,2/3,3/4,1/1$$

The sub-intervals are

$$[0/1,1/4],[1/4,1/3],[1/3,1/2],[1/2,2/3],[2/3,3/4],[3/4,1/1]$$

We add the length of the sub-intervals whose start-points have even denominators.

$$(1/3-1/4)+(2/3-1/2)+(1-3/4)=1/2$$

And add the length of the sub-intervals whose start-points have odd denominators

$$(1/4-0)+(1/2-1/3)+(3/4-2/3)=1/2$$

## Question

As $n\to \infty$, what would be the length of the sub-intervals whose start-point has even denominators? What would be the length of the sub-intervals whose start-point has odd denominators?

## Attempt

```
    H = DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort[Select[Flatten[Table[a/b, {b, 1, 20}, {a, 1, 20}]], 
    Between[#, {0, 1}] &]]]
h1 = Position[
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort[Select[Flatten[Table[a/b, {b, 1, 20}, {a, 1, 20}]], 
     Between[#, {0, 1}] &]]], EvenQ[Denominator[#]] == True &]
h2 = Position[
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort[Select[Flatten[Table[a/b, {b, 1, 20}, {a, 1, 20}]], 
     Between[#, {0, 1}] &]]], OddQ[Denominator[#]] == True &]
S = Total[Differences[[Flatten[h1]]]] + 
  Total[Differences[[Flatten[h2]]]]
```

Unfortunately for $S$ I get `0`. How do we fix this?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but perhaps `FareySequence[]` might help: `With[{n = 4}, Total[#.{-1, 1} & /@ GatherBy[Partition[FareySequence[n], 2, 1], OddQ @* Denominator @* First], {2}]]`

Comment: @J.M. I think that's correct. Thanks!

Comment: @J.M. Are you unable to answer my question because it is not clear?

Comment: More like I've no idea how to solve the $n\to\infty$ case; what I provided is of course only valid for finite $n$.

Comment: 1) Your title is terrible. A title should be a concise description of the to problem you a re having. Your title describes nothing. 2) Why is [0, 1/4] classified as a sub-interval starting with a number having an odd denominator? Are you taking it be 0/1? If so, you should make this clear in your question.

Comment: @m_goldberg fixed it.